# Dockerfile "unable to select packages" linux alpine

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, alpine-linux, libssl

Today I have lunched a pipeline on DevOps to generate a docker image and I encountered a problem.

Dockerfile fragment:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS base             
RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib dotnet6-sdk

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
.
. 
.
```

I'm getting this error message when building a docker image:

```
#7 [build  2/11] RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib dotnet6-sdk
#7 0.353 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 0.514 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 0.900 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#7 0.901   libssl1.1 (no such package):
#7 0.901     required by: world[libssl1.1]
#7 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib dotnet6-sdk" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Latest version of Alpine (**3.19.0**) was released on 07 Dec 2023.
If I lunch the pipeline with this modified version of dockerfile it works:

```
FROM alpine:3.18.5 AS base             
RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib dotnet6-sdk

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
.
. 
.
```

Probably the problem concerns the new version of Alpine which no longer uses the "libssl1.1" library.
I checked the [release note](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.19.0) and found nothing about changes or deprecation of the "libssl" library.

How do I know if the library is still needed?
How can I understand which version of the library I need to use?

I created the dockerfile taking inspiration from  [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-alpine#dependencies).

Comment: You are wrongly assuming here that the package of a distribution is maintained by the distribution itself. libssl1.1 will most likely not be on Alpine 3.19, though, as raised by the project page: https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: ^- _Note: The latest stable version is the 3.2 series supported until 23rd November 2025. Also available is the 3.1 series supported until 14th March 2025, and the 3.0 series which is a Long Term Support (LTS) version and is supported until 7th September 2026. All older versions (including 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.0 and 0.9.8) are now out of support and should not be used. Users of these older versions are encouraged to upgrade to 3.2 or 3.0 as soon as possible._

Comment: Last but not least, this should come in handy for you: [https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libssl*&branch=v3.19&repo=&arch=&maintainer=)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you for the clarification. I actually checked Alpine's release notes but I didn't check the library's official website, missing this important detail. The last link you sent me is perfect for checking the libraries supported by Alpine! I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, would you mind briefly sharing your insights in the answer? I will help others with similar concerns. Appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score 6):

I changed libssl1.1 with libssl3 and it works with Alpine (3.19.0)

Comment: I have updated the Microsoft documentation, section "Dependencies".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-alpine